# jquery load() is not working only when classlevel @requestMapping("something")

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

I'm working on spring mvc and I successfully imported external html to my jsp page using jquery load() function. but when I assign class level reqeust mapping, it's not loading anything.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>List Articles</title>
<link href="<c:url value= "/resources/css/aa.css" />" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<c:url value= "/resources/smartmenus/sm-core-css.css" />"
    rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<c:url value= "/resources/smartmenus/sm-blue.css" />"
    rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="<c:url value= "/resources/js/jquery.min.js" />"></script>
<script
    src="<c:url value = "/resources/smartmenus/jquery.smartmenus.min.js" />"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#nav1').load('resources/html/nav.jsp');
        $('#header1').load('resources/html/header.html');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header1"></div>
    <div id="nav1"></div>
    <p>hello</p>


</body>
</html>
```

since /resources/css/aa.css part is sccessfully loaded, I don't think the problem is about failing to locate the /resources path.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("withOutThisWorksFine")
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() throws Exception {
        return "home"
    }
}
```

Comment: `@RequestMapping("withOutThisWorksFine")` at the class and `@GetMapping("/")` at the method is the same as no annotation at the class and `@GetMapping("withOutThisWorksFine/")` at the method. The methods path is always relative to the path specified for the class, whether it starts with `/` or not.

Comment: @Andreas thank you very much. at least I realized it was nothing about class level mapping.